# I've been doing work for a side business all year, but I only opened my LLC last month. Can I declare all the prior income as business income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, income

In January I started work with another company that paid me as a consultant without a contract. In September I created an LLC to formalize things & get tax advantages. When I pay my taxes can I claim that all the side income I made from Jan to Aug was income of this LLC even though it technically wasn't formed yet?

Comment: What difference in tax treatment are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

> When I pay my taxes can I claim that all the side income I made from Jan to Aug was income of this LLC even though it technically wasn't formed yet?

Obviously, not. How can an entity that doesn't exist earn income?

> I created an LLC to formalize things & get tax advantages

There would be absolutely no tax advantages to creating an LLC over sole proprietorship, and there's absolutely no requirement from tax perspective to create one.

Comment: you say "obviously not" but you can do this in the UK so it's not at all obvious.

Comment: @JackAidley the question is tagged "united-states". I don't know what you can do in the UK, but in the US entity that doesn't exist cannot be active. In any case, for tax purposes LLCs are disregarded in the US.

Comment: A US based answer is obviously fine; it is asserting that it is obvious that you can't do this that isn't. It is not obvious because you can in other first world countries.

Comment: @JackAidley can you provide any reference? My common sense tells me that it is impossible to earn income without existing.

Comment: Reference: personal experience :). Can you provide any reference that it is not possible in the US? I think this answer needs it.

Comment: As I understand it, you are allowed to do this because it is common for a company to be created in response to a need; you have the work so you create the company in response. It doesn't make sense to delay the work because your sorting out the details of the company.

Comment: @JackAidley in the US LLCs are disregarded for tax purposes, so the question doesn't even make sense. What you're describing may be organizational delays, but in the US LLCs can be created very quickly (in some States within 24 hours), so I doubt that such an explanation would hold. But even then - it would make absolutely no difference for tax purposes.