# Can I count personal 1099 income as LLC revenue?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, limited-liability-company, form-1099

I have about 78k in 1099 income that was made out to me personally. I also recently formed an LLC with the election to be taxed as an S-corp - can I report this 1099 income as revenue to the LLC, rather than as Schedule C income? Or somehow convert it to LLC revenue? Can I pay my LLC somehow perhaps?

Comment: Another similar question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153472/ive-been-doing-work-for-a-side-business-all-year-but-i-only-opened-my-llc-last/153478#153478

Comment: Where were you planning to report this income if not a Schedule C? Are you intending to elect to have the LLC taxed as an S-Corp?

Comment: More importantly, what difference do you expect it to make if you report it through LLC?

Comment: I'll just put this here for future readers to see how the story ends: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154354/understanding-the-timing-of-revoking-s-corp-election-for-an-llc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a good question

However, both money paid directly to you and money paid to your LLC will be showing up on your Schedule C on the 1040 (unless you’ve elected S-Corp status for your LLC?)

If your LLC is not an S-Corp, it makes very little difference, as it will all flow through Schedule C.

If your LLC IS an S-Corp, you should contact your client and ask them to amend the 1099 with your correct information. Send them the W9 that has your EIN rather than your SSN. But technically, if you are an S-Corp, the client wouldn’t need to issue a 1099 in the first place (assuming you are neither a lawyer nor a healthcare professional).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: All income for a single-member LLC is self-employment income. For an S-corp, 60% of income might be salary and 40% of the income might be dividend. However, some sources say that a single-member S-corp could be determined to be a disregarded entity just like a single-member LLC.

Comment: Both the answer and @SSpring's comment are incorrect and misleading. One cannot "amend" 1099, 1099 is issued to the entity that was paid. The OP was paid as an individual, so I doubt anyone would go about backdating contracts to change the 1099 to a non-existent at the time S-Corp. As to the comment - there's absolutely no rule that 40% of the income could be reported as dividend. If all the income is earned through the personal services of the OP - why would not all of it be characterized as salary? Any such mischaracterization without proper justification would be fraudulent tax evasion.

Comment: @littleadv none of the 1099 income was salary, because I was not an employee. It does seem pretty clear that LLCs taxed as an S-corp do in fact pay members in dividends, or more accurately "distributions", as long as it is a "reasonable" amount, though people all seem to define 'reasonable" differently. Why are you suggesting otherwise?

Comment: https://www.collective.com/blog/money-management/freelancers-guide-to-paying-yourself-a-salary-from-an-s-corporation/

Comment: https://www.wolterskluwer.com/en/expert-insights/lower-your-employment-taxes-by-operating-as-an-s-corporation

Comment: @number41 I'm not suggesting otherwise, I'm suggesting that funneling your earned income through S-Corp to not pay taxes is fraudulent tax evasion. You can find a lot of blogs describing a lot of illegal schemes, that doesn't make them legal. Reasonable salary should represent a reasonable compensation for your personal services. If the S-Corp revenues are entirely generated by your personal services - what would be the reasonable explanation for different treatment of some of that?

Comment: @littleadv are you really suggesting that Wolters is recommending illegal tax evasion? It really seems you are stretching. You seem to be answering your own question - the IRS docs are pretty clear that anything beyond the reasonable salary can be given as a distribution. You don’t seem to be defining “personal services” - the service is the same whether provided by the person or the LLC. Any service is always done by a person. The LLC isn’t some robot doing it on its own.

Comment: If the S-corp is not determined to be a disregarded entity then it can operate as an S-corp. Getting the personal payment into the S-corp is a problem. Well, where did the funds go ? Were they deposited in a personal bank account and then transferred to the S-corp account ? Did the S-corp write a memo for the situation ? Does the S-corp write memos for all situations and add them to the company books ? Now a letter of explanation could be included with the tax forms but if rejected then there is more work to do.

Comment: @number41 you should read what Wolters is writing more carefully, because what's been suggested in this answer and the comment below it is not at all what Wolters is suggesting. You should also understand what "personal services" mean. Arbitrarily deciding that what you personally earn as a contractor suddenly becomes unreasonable to be paid as salary is fraudulent, yes.

Comment: @SSpring bookkeeping and management requirements aside (LLC has much less stringent requirements than a Corporation, regardless of tax treatment), the question here is whether S-Corp can be used to mischaracterize the *source* of income and transform it from *earned* to *passive*. The answer is absolutely not.

Comment: @littleadv no one can know what you mean by "personal services" if you don't explain yourself, but feel free.  No one can know what you are referring to in the Wolters article either, if you don't explain. If you have any concrete references to what is possible or not according to the law, that would be the thing to actually write here. The somewhat arbitrary nature of "reasonable" salary vs distributions in an S-corp seems to be entirely the case according to the IRS website. There is no rule given. I know what typical salaries are in my profession. Do you have any references for anything?

Comment: The counter comments are basically saying that a single-member S-corp must determine itself to be a disregarded entity or else it's a situation of tax evasion. That's not how the situation works. A entity can attempt to be an S-corp and then the IRS can possibly take a position against the S-corp. There is no intent of tax evasion but just an administrative process.

Comment: @number41 there absolutely are rules. Start with the IRC Sec. 269A. That's just *one* legal reference that describes both what "personal services" means and how a potential scenario described in this answer and implied by you would be tax evasion.

Comment: @SSpring no, that's not what I'm saying. You can absolutely be an S-Corp and pay yourself a reasonable salary that would adequately reflect the value of your personal services. If the S-Corp *only* exists due to *your* personal services (and not, say, goodwill, employees, licensing, or other sources of income) - then it stands to reason that all S-Corp revenues are due to *your personal work* and as such what S-Corp charges clients should be spent on your salary.

Comment: @number41 here's a more detailed explanation not by someone peddling S-Corps: https://www.collective.com/blog/money-management/freelancers-guide-to-paying-yourself-a-salary-from-an-s-corporation/#A_reasonable_salary_is_a_must. Bottom line is that for software engineers you'll *at most* be able to shave off some of the FICA taxes (only the SS portion, essentially, since medicare will be on your personal tax return anyway). That if you're able to show that you're such a horrible SWE that you'll get paid well below market, but at the same time justify your S-Corp charging your clients much more.

Comment: A single-shareholder S-corp can only pay distributions in the percentage of the passive income to total income ? Everything else is salary ? No one knows what to do with the IRS code. Do something else and wait for a letter explaining the IRS position. Then accept the IRS position or else litigate. There is no tax evasion attempt when everything is disclosed.

Comment: @number41 I only pointed out that the answer as provided is wrong. You asked for a legal reference and I provided that to you. What's rude in that? I understand that you *don't want* to pay taxes, and that's fine. I'm trying to explain to you that what you *want* doesn't always matter. Including with regards to who and how comments on your posts on this site.

Comment: I like the viewpoint of the single-shareholder S-corp having percentage distributions equal to the percentage of passive income. Now this viewpoint is only for a single-shareholder S-corp. But wow, an S-corp is limited to 25% passive income ! S-corp passive income beyond 25% goes at the C-corp income rate. S-corp passive income beyond 25% for three years in a row requires the S-corp to become a C-corp. However, a single-shareholder C-corp with passive income is likely to be determined to be a personal-holding-company, and face large tax penalties, if the passive income is 60% or more.

Comment: If the single-shareholder S-corp has 25% or more passive income, but less than 60% passive income, then just convert to C-corp ? Well, if the C-corp pays dividends then the result is double taxation in that case. So convert to C-corp and draw a salary only ? Sure, but if the C-corp builds up a large amount of value then it can be subject to accumulated-earnings-tax. Well, the overall context here is that some single-member LLC's are converting to single-shareholder S-corp.